# How to make the left and right padding of the android-seekbar disappear

Tags: android-seekbar

I have the following xml:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/sk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="120"
    android:background="#44ff0000"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    />
```

Why the seekbar still has spaces as the picture shows, how can I make them disappear?

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwwYw.png)

Comment: Post the rest of your xml file as well

Comment: The seekbar above is surrounded by a RelativeLayout with android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content", no more else, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use following lines in java.

```
SeekBar sk = (SeekBar)findViewByID(R.id.sk);
sk.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use these 2 lines in your Seekbar xml

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

Answere in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42509109/5819451