# AppCompatSeekBar left and right padding removal?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androiddesignsupport, android-seekbar

[image: refer image]

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.SocialMob.CustomViews.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCurrentDurationMusic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="01:00"
                android:textColor="#AEAEAE"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarMusic"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:max="100"
                android:paddingLeft="0px"
                android:thumbOffset="-1px"
                android:paddingRight="0px"
                android:progress="60"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                app:theme="@style/SeekBarTheme"
                app:paddingEnd="0px"
                app:paddingStart="0px" />

            <com.SocialMob.CustomViews.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTotalDurationMusic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:text="05:00"
                android:textColor="#AEAEAE"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Am doing an music player app which has SeekBar, I want to remove extra padding in both ends of SeekBar. I have tried 0 padding, 0 margin, -ve padding and -ve margin.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not try modify it by java code.try the following sample code.

```
 seekBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This may helps you.

Answer (score 26):

Set following attributes.

> android:paddingStart="0dp"
>   android:paddingEnd="0dp"